# How to use dhtmlx sheduler in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I use dhtmlx scheduler to manage events .I successfully import the js files but i have no idea to save data in data base and i am using spring boot.
can you help me

Comment: Hi You are asking how to save data in the database using spring boot, but your question is marked angular, and  you refer to dhtml. You need to understand that the database, and spring boot are on the server side, angular and dhtml are client side. in order to save something from the user, you first need to send the data to the server, from the client, and put the data in the database.It is not clear which part you are having trouble with. If it is the whole part, start in one place, and tackle one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of database do you use ?

With script you can add event like this : 
    `scheduler.addEvent({
        start_date: "16-06-2013 09:00",
        end_date:   "16-06-2013 12:00",
        text:   "Meeting",
        holder: "John", // userdata
        room:   "5"     // userdata
    });`this :

Documentation link : 
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_addevent.html

Comment: and I use MySql database